# How to clone a texture from other UV Map Image in the Texture Paint Mode in Blender 2.77a?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, versions

I am following [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/sZDMFkj8GqA?t=7m48s) to clone a texture from another UV Map in the **Texture Paint Mode**. However, I cannot find out the locations of `Tool` and the `Clone` option bar. It seems that the locations are changed in my version of Blender. I am now using **Blender 2.77a**. How to find out the locations of them?

The left-hand side is captured from the video. The right-hand side is captured from my Blender.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out how to set the <kbd>Clone</kbd>.

### Steps

The following step is under **Blender 2.77a** in **Ubuntu**.

1. Go to `Texture Paint` mode.

   [image]
2. According to the following image, you can click <kbd>Brush</kbd> -> <kbd>Image Paint Tool</kbd> -> <kbd>Clone</kbd>.

   [image]
3. Set the `Brush` to clone.

   [image]
4. Go to `Option` and configure the setting like the following.

   [image]
5. Go to `Slots` and select the `Paint Mode` as `Image`.

   [image]
6. Create a new `Canvas Image` and rename it as what you want. e.g. `Casper Texture`.

   [image]
7. Set the `UV Map` you want to paint it to.

   [image]
8. Check the checkbox `Clone from image/UV map`.

   [image]
9. Select the `Source Clone UV/Map`.

   [image]
10. Select the image of the UV/Map you want to clone.

    [image]
11. Paint it.

    [image]
12. Save your painted UV/Map image.

    [image]

### References

- [Blender - "Micky" Ch.1 - Pt. 9 - Texture painting with Clone Brush](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DooeJwglbDU)

Comment: That's not how to set the clone; that is how to switch to the clone brush.

Comment: thank you for sharing! this should be put somewhere in the blender documentation